# How to create Access User Form to both look up and add data

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access form that contains two subforms. The main form has three dropdown fields that allow the user to pick what data is displayed in the two linked subforms. The dropdown fields are all unbound as they are referenced in the datasource of the main form.

The SQL of the datasource for the main form is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl_RptPeriod.RptPrdID, tbl_BusUnits.UnitID, tbl_Categories.CategoryID, tbl_Categories.CategoryTitle, tbl_Categories.CategoryGroup, tbl_Categories.Inactive, tbl_Categories.RptPrdID, tbl_Categories.UnitID
FROM tbl_RptPeriod INNER JOIN (tbl_BusUnits INNER JOIN tbl_Categories ON tbl_BusUnits.UnitID = tbl_Categories.UnitID) ON tbl_RptPeriod.RptPrdID = tbl_Categories.RptPrdID
WHERE (((tbl_RptPeriod.RptPrdID)=[Forms]![Compliance]![cmbReportPeriod]) AND ((tbl_BusUnits.UnitID)=[Forms]![Compliance]![cmbBusinessUnit]) AND ((tbl_Categories.CategoryID)=[Forms]![Compliance]![CategoryTitle]));
```

This works perfectly to look up records. However, I want the users to be able to add new records to the ones they are looking up. That doesn't work as it should.

I can add records, but then the form elements that I am using to look up the data, specifically `RptPrdID`,`UnitID`, and `CategoryID` are not being populated in the table, thus the new records are unassociated and don't show up if you go to look for them again in the main form after closing it or moving to another record.

This makes sense in so far as the form elements I am using in the "WHERE" criteria of the SQL are unbound, but of course, if I add a new record, I want it to be correctly matched. The user must be able to find the records he adds if he looks up the same criteria again.

**Question:**
How can I get new records entered in the subforms to have `RptPrdID`,`UnitID`, and `CategoryID` filled in?

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT tbl_Activity.CategoryID AS CategoryID_X, tbl_Activity.RptPrdID AS RptPrdID_X, tbl_Activity.UnitID AS UnitID_X, tbl_Categories.SortKey, tbl_Categories.CategoryTitle, tbl_Categories.CategoryGroup, tbl_Categories.Inactive, tbl_Categories.Inactive, tbl_BusUnits.Unit_Name, tbl_RptPeriod.Rep_Month_Nr, tbl_RptPeriod.Rep_Month_Name, tbl_RptPeriod.Rep_Year
FROM tbl_RptPeriod INNER JOIN (tbl_Categories INNER JOIN (tbl_BusUnits INNER JOIN tbl_Activity ON tbl_BusUnits.UnitID = tbl_Activity.UnitID) ON tbl_Categories.CategoryID = tbl_Activity.CategoryID) ON tbl_RptPeriod.RptPrdID = tbl_Activity.RptPrdID
WHERE (((tbl_Activity.CategoryID)=[Forms]![Compliance_EXPERIMENT]![cmbCategoryTitle]) AND ((tbl_Activity.RptPrdID)=[Forms]![Compliance_EXPERIMENT]![cmbReportPeriod]) AND ((tbl_Activity.UnitID)=[Forms]![Compliance_EXPERIMENT]![cmbBusinessUnit]))
ORDER BY tbl_Categories.SortKey;
```

I had to change the query somewhat, but the key fields are still the same ones, though they are now on a different table.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.RptPrdID_X = Me.cmbReportPeriod
    Me.UnitID_X = Me.cmbBusinessUnit
    Me.CategoryID_X = Me.cmbCategoryTitle
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add code for filling those 3 fields in `Before Insert` event of main form

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Me.RptPrdID = Me.cmbReportPeriod
Me.UnitID = Me.cmbBusinessUnit
Me.CategoryID = Me.CategoryTitle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I new it had to be something simple, but I wasn't getting it!

Comment: Sergey, I changed part of my form, and the solution is not working anymore. I checked to ensure that the controls have the appropriate name and that the record source is also specified correctly, but it still doesn't work. What could cause that?

Comment: What was changed and what is error message or what doesn't work? Make sure that the form displays data correctly and comboboxes also show right data. Make sure that you can change data in the form manually (query is still updateable). Make sure that the code compiles without errors.

Comment: The form shows the data correctly. I can enter data, but when I do, the fields that are described above are simply left blank. I don't get an error message. I've compiled the database but it has no effect. I will repost the query as it has changed somewhat... maybe you will see something in that which I don't

Comment: You added new table to the query with the same field names, it may cause automatic renaming of query fields names to something like "Expr1". Run the query and check field names, give new aliases to required fields and select those fields in form's field's Control Source property

Comment: I changed the names of the query fields using aliases as you suggested, but the before insert is still not working. I updated the `BeforeInsert` as well so you can take a look at it.

Comment: Did you change control names on the form? I'd recommend to add `Option Explicit` to each VBA module and recompile the code, it will show if you have wrong names

Comment: you need while looking at code to do a debug compile. If errors exist,t hen you have to fix such error. And since your inserting records in the subform, then of course that sub form will NOT have and NOT allow you to use the field names in the main form. That before insert event is of course in your sub form. So first, do the debug compile and fix all code errors. Next up, you can in that sub form reference the parent values and controls using me.Parent.NameOfControlInParentFormGoesHere

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal That was it! I needed to put it in the subform! Now it updates! Thank you for your Help.

Comment: @SergeyS. THank you too you as well for taking the time to further look at my problem. I appreciate it!